# mask the middle number using the JCL

Tags: dfsort

i have requrement like this. could you please help any one help me?

i have 16 digit length fileld in my input file. if more than 13 digit length then first 4 digit as it is and last 4 digits as it is and mask the remaining the number
if less than 13 then keep the number as it is.

```
example
IP file

0000359681243354 
0000359681243354 
810176733 

OP

00003̶5̶9̶6̶8̶1̶2̶4̶3354 
00003̶5̶9̶6̶8̶1̶2̶4̶3354 
810176733
```

Comment: Mahesh, JCL won’t help apart from being able to schedule a job step that could process the files.  What you’d most likely want to do is write a Rexx program to process the input files and perform the functions you outlined.

Comment: @Hogstrom or a convoluted sort

Comment: @Mahesh - please refrain from using the JCL tag unless you are asking a JCL question. This is a sort question. Also, please do not ask the same question on multiple forums. You have been given a suggested solution elsewhere. I recommend this topic be held/deleted.

Comment: please can you send me the rexx code for this one?

Comment: If you re-ask this question, or amend it, please clarify what "mask" means. In the given example, you are marking the digits "3̶5̶9̶6̶8̶1̶2̶4̶" with strikethrough, but i suspect you really want them removed from the file. The given output should be what you _actually_ want to obtain, so we know the correct answer, and can reply accordingly.

Comment: @Mahesh - you asked: please can you send me the rexx code for this one? Why a Rexx program? This is very easy in sort: IFTHEN and OVERLAY or BUILD. You are expected to write your own code and then be helped to correct it if it is wrong and you cannot debug it. Any data set size over 20-30,000 records is not suitable for Rexx processing anyway.

Comment: @Turophile- Mask means whatever data dont visisble in out put data set.example we can write the out put like this 0000-------3354 instead of strikethrough

Comment: sorry @NicC..i was msiuderstodd your comment..iam new to the jCL thats why i was asked the code...do you have any sample code related this requrement  then i can modify and try it myself..

Comment: @Mahesh - You may be new to JCL but JCL is the least of you problems at the moment. Your problem is to do with which sort control statements to use. I have told you. They are described in the DFsortApplication Programming Guide which is freely available at your workplace. That will even tell you the JCL you require to run your sort although you will have to tailor it to your shop standards and the specific data set names you need. Finally, Rexx is a programming language and nothing to do with either JCL or DFsort. Really, you should be asking your colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1:**
As per @NicC's suggestions in the Comments section of this answer, you may try the following code:

```
  INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT,BUILD=(1,16)), 
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=(13,1,CH,NE,X'40',AND,13,1,CH,NE,X'00'),OVERLAY=(5:8C'-'))
  SORT FIELDS=COPY
```

**Alternatively,** you may also try the following code.

Firstly, we use `OUTFIL` with `FTOV,VLTRIM=C' '` to convert the input records to VB with an RDW. This is helpful because we can access the RDW to get the length of data upto first nonblank character. But, **how to access the RDW?** See next step.

Secondly, we build a record in T2 file, with actual data, followed by the length of the data (RDW is in `1,2,BI`. Subtract 4 from `1,2,BI` to get the length of data).

Lastly, use `INREC IFTHEN` to check if the length of the data is `GE` 13 or not. Format data as required.

**Note:** *Following code needs to be changed for DD names, position of the 16 digit length field and other input fields in the  record.*

```
//STEP1 EXEC PGM=ICETOOL
//TOOLMSG DD SYSOUT=*
//DFSMSG  DD SYSOUT=*
//IN DD DSN=...  input file (FB)
//TEMP1 DD DSN=&&TEMP1,UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(5,5)),DISP=(,PASS)
//TEMP2 DD DSN=&&TEMP2,UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(5,5)),DISP=(,PASS)
//OUT DD DSN=...  output file (FB)
//TOOLIN DD *
COPY FROM(IN) USING(CTL1)
COPY FROM(TEMP1) TO(TEMP2) USING(CTL2)
COPY FROM(TEMP2) TO(OUT) USING(CTL3)
/*
//CTL1CNTL DD *
  OUTFIL FNAMES=TEMP1,FTOV,VLTRIM=C' '
/*
//CTL2CNTL DD *
  OUTFIL FNAMES=TEMP2,VTOF,
    BUILD=(5,16,X,1,2,BI,SUB,+4,TO=ZD,LENGTH=2)
/*
//CTL3CNTL DD *
  INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=(18,2,ZD,GE,13),BUILD=(1:1,4,5:8C'-',13:13,4),
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=(18,2,ZD,LT,13),BUILD=(1:1,6))
  SORT FIELDS=COPY
```

Comment: What a convuluted way! Why convert to VB it does nothing to add to the ease of solution and you have to convert back again. Simply check the record for not blank in column 14. If not blank then overlay bytes 5 to 12 with the masking character. Or one could use build but overlay is simpler. But what we do not know is if the data set is VB or FB. Nor do we know the LRECL, without which we are just shooting in the dark.

Comment: Hi @NicC I had initially thought of checking the 13th byte for non blank but I just don't remember why I chose this method. We might still be shooting in the dark, as there are many combinations of input (input < 16 bytes, input having digits with spaces in between, input with low values and so on) for which, writing a code in COBOL might help.